# IE removes option tags created with javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, innerhtml

So I have this following code that works great for every browser I've tested so far, except IE

```
var array = eval( '(' + xmlHttp.responseText + ')' );
var html = '';

for(var key in array)
{
    html += '<option value="' + key  + '">' +array[key] + '</option>';
}
alert(html);
document.getElementById('countries').innerHTML = html;
```

The problem stands at the `.innerHTML`. The alert prints the data as it should be, but the inner strips the tag and I end up with words in a row.

So, any ideas how to possibility fix that issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known issue that IE doesn't let you use `.innerHTML` to set `option` elements in a `select`.

You should be creating elements using DOM methods instead.

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for(var key in array) {
    var opt = fragment.appendChild(document.createElement("option"));
    opt.value = key; 
    opt.text = array[key];
}

document.getElementById('countries').appendChild(fragment);
```

And if `array` is an actual Array, then use `for` instead of `for-in` in JavaScript.

And if you need to empty the `select` first, you can do that with `.innerHTML = ""`, or better, with a loop:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('countries');
while (sel.firstChild)
    sel.removeChild(firstChild);

sel.appendChild(fragment);
```

Comment: thank you, but if it's not to much to ask... an example would be really useful

Comment: Thanks, great info. No, I don't need to empty the `select` as it starts empty but good to know a good way of doing it

Answer (score 3):

```
var select = document.getElementById('countries'); // assuming this is your <select>
for (var key in array) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = key;
    option.text = array[key];
    select.appendChild(option);
}
```